# How to convert Row values to columns and adding 3 columns under single value in SQL

Tags: mysql

I have a data at redshift and using MySQL to pull the required information from it.

[Data Available in Redshift](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tRpdq.png)

For a particular name, the average, maximum and minimum values will saved on regular time intervals on each day.

The required output is that for each name the maximum of average, maximum of maximum and maximum of minimum columns should come on a day basis.

[Output Format](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fttTo.png)

The problem is that Date created is in the row values and need to be in the column header. For each day, the 3 sub columns of Avg, Max and Min needed.

Please help me to get the required output.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You can have this as a solution but I don't think there's a way do have a way to have a column as a header above three columns

```
select name, 
round(avg(case when created = '2016-10-01' then average else null end),3) '1st October avg', 
round(max(case when created = '2016-10-01' then maximum else null end),3) '1st October max', 
round(min(case when created = '2016-10-01' then minimum else null end),3) '1st October min',
round(avg(case when created = '2016-10-02' then average else null end),3) '2nd October avg', 
round(max(case when created = '2016-10-02' then maximum else null end),3) '2nd October max', 
round(min(case when created = '2016-10-02' then minimum else null end),3) '2nd October min',
round(avg(case when created = '2016-10-03' then average else null end),3) '3rd October avg', 
round(max(case when created = '2016-10-03' then maximum else null end),3) '3rd October max', 
round(min(case when created = '2016-10-03' then minimum else null end),3) '3rd October min'
from
(select 'hp001' name, 0.28 average, 0.33 maximum, 0.25 minimum, '2016-10-01' created union
select 'hp002' name, 0.28 average, 0.33 maximum, 0.25 minimum, '2016-10-01' created union
select 'hp003' name, 0.28 average, 0.35 maximum, 0.25 minimum, '2016-10-01' created union
select 'hp001' name, 0.28 average, 0.33 maximum, 0.25 minimum, '2016-10-01' created union
select 'hp002' name, 0.28 average, 0.35 maximum, 0.25 minimum, '2016-10-02' created union
select 'hp003' name, 0.27 average, 0.33 maximum, 0.24 minimum, '2016-10-02' created union
select 'hp001' name, 0.27 average, 0.33 maximum, 0.24 minimum, '2016-10-02' created union
select 'hp002' name, 0.28 average, 0.34 maximum, 0.25 minimum, '2016-10-02' created union
select 'hp003' name, 0.28 average, 0.33 maximum, 0.23 minimum, '2016-10-03' created union
select 'hp001' name, 0.28 average, 0.33 maximum, 0.25 minimum, '2016-10-03' created union
select 'hp002' name, 0.28 average, 0.34 maximum, 0.22 minimum, '2016-10-03' created union
select 'hp003' name, 0.28 average, 0.33 maximum, 0.25 minimum, '2016-10-03' created) t group by name;
```

Comment: Thanks MontyPython. But the data is dynamically change on each day and it will not work for me.